# Will a short be automatically converted to a byte?

Tags: java

On page 14 here:

http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~cconway/teaching/cs1007/notes/types.pdf

Always assume the conversion fits:

Reading notes from Columbia, it states that a long will be automatically converted to an int/short/byte and and int will be automatically converted to a short/byte, but leaves off the last obvious conversion ( short to byte ).

Is this omission a mistake or actually the way the language functions?

Is there any way to test this?

Here it is graphically

- long->int,short,byte
- int->short,byte
- short->byte
- byte

Comment: I don't think the notes are correct re: longs. A long literal can't automatically be converted to a smaller data type.

Comment: @chrylis have you actually tried it? There's no reason for it to be legal. If you have a literal that needs to fit in a smaller datatype, just don't put the L on the end. For an example, see: http://ideone.com/eo2HH6

Comment: @DHall Apparently I was misremembering from some time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, notice that the text is talking about compile time constant expressions. Narrowing conversions are allowed only for compile time constant expressions. From the [language specification, section 5.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2-300):

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type byte, short, char, or int:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.

The fact that there is an implicit narrowing assignment conversion from compile-time constant `short` to `byte` is not immediately obvious because there are no `short` literal values; only `int` and `long`. To obtain a compile time constant `short` you have to use a trick like one of the below:

```
// Casting:
byte b2 = (short) 42;

// Compile-time constant short value:
static final short s = 42;
byte b = s;
```

On the other hand, your lecture notes also say that there is an implicit narrowing conversion from `long` to `int` and smaller integer types. This is incorrect, the conversion can only be used when the expression is of type `byte`, `short`, `char`, or `int`. The code fragment they use to illustrate produces a compile-time error:

```
int i = 0x12345678L; /* "error: possible loss of precision" */
```

Comment: is datatype is different to literal?

Comment: @Joni pls can u explain

Comment: @employee-0 No, `10L` is a long, but the compiler can see that it will fit into a `byte`, so it's legal as a constant assignment.

Comment: `10L` is a `long` literal. The compiler is allowed to automatically narrow that `long` into a `byte` because it can see at compile time that it will fit with no loss of data. You couldn't do the same thing with `1000L`.

Comment: @Joni - can you please explain to chrylis why his answer is wrong.

Comment: @chrylis: The compiler is not allowed the automatically narrow `long` to `byte`; narrowing conversions are permitted only for `int` and smaller types.